# Error #2038 IO error When Implementing Uploadify in asp.net site

Tags: uploadify

I have searched for IO issue in forums and found many questions on the same topic but topic leads to any solution so can someone from uploadify.com help me to resolve my issue here is the link of my Sample Application which is created in asp.net C# : http://www.mediafire.com/?cale04it8susavv

I have created the Discussion on Uploadify Forums also i have pasted the detailed code if any 1 don't want to download the code here is the link : http://www.uploadify.com/forums/discussion/7475/error-2038-io-error-when-implementing-uploadify-in-asp.net-site/#Item_1

Whenever i upload file i get rickjackson.jpg (1.65KB) - IO Error Please help me to solve this issue...

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I am able to solve my issue here is the link to know the answer : http://forums.asp.net/t/1688871.aspx/1?Error+2038+IO+error+When+Implementing+Uploadify+in+asp+net+site

regards,

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: Keep in mind that with ASP hosting, by default an ASP/ASP.NET script does not have write access to the root directory or subdirectories of a hosting account. If you want to specify write access to the root directory or a subdirectory, you must define write access to that directory through the FTP File Manager option in your hosting account settings. You can also use the IIS Settings to set up a "Virtual Root" in IIS by selecting the Set Application Root option.

http://community.godaddy.com/help/3970/what-is-the-absolute-or-direct-path-for-my-windows-asp-hosting-account